# Doubly Connected Graph Interface Desgin

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, graph, interface

I have a `directed graph (DAG)` with nodes of several types.
Each type has its own implementation of `Ensure Outgoing Link`, which adds another node to the list of outgoing nodes.

This graph is doubly connected, so `Ensure Outgoing Link` also calls `Ensure Incoming Link` which adds the reverse link so that the graph can be traversed in either direction.

`Ensure Incoming Link` does not call `Ensure Outgoing Link`, as that would create a circle.  So the problem is **trying to stop consumers of the nodes from calling `Ensure Incoming Link` (as that would create an incomplete graph), while still allowing the implementation of the Node to call it.**

Solutions I see are to either:

1. Have the graph data structure itself do all the link management
2. Or to have the node cast itself from the interface to the actual class.
3. Or to comment or name the `Ensure Incoming Link` so no one else uses it.

The only issue with having the graph object do it is that each type of node has their own slightly different version of adding an outgoing node, so it still needs to have a method which could be called externally if I'm not careful.

What would be a good design here?

Comment: Please provide a snippet to show what have you done so far to make it easy for other to suggest possible solutions/ideas. Please consider providing a minimum viable code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a directed graph with nodes of several types, each type has its own implementation of "Ensure Outgoing Link", which adds another node to the list of outgoing nodes.

A directed graph shouldn't necessarily have edges in both direction on each node/vertex, maybe you meant undirected graph?

I can't provide an accurate/detailed answer to your question since you didn't provide enough details as to what has been done so far.

> This graph is doubly connected, so Ensure Outgoing Link also calls Ensure Incoming Link

I assume `Ensure Outgoing Link` and `Ensure Incoming Link` are methods, methods in general should do one thing and should do only what it say/claim to be doing in a class.

Since `Ensure Outgoing link` "adds another node to the list of outgoing nodes." making it call `Ensure Incoming Link` will make on of these methods redundant and does two things that's (Adding "incoming" and "outgoing" link/edge). Also, `EnsureXXX` is a misleading name, what "ensure" is/signify here?

> Ensure Incoming Link does not call Ensure Outgoing Link, as that would create a circle. So the problem is trying to stop consumers of the nodes from calling Ensure Incoming Link (as that would create an incomplete graph), while still allowing the implementation of the Node to call it.

One thing here, you could create an interface and hides these methods (not exposing them in the interface), for example methods that could be exposed through the `IDagGraph` interface would be something like:

1. `AddEdge` (in-there you could do whatever validation you want without exposing the validation methods outside the class)
2. `AddNode`
3. `FindShortestPath(Node a, Node b)`
4. etc...